# Excel VBA. Copy and Paste Uneven Data Range to another Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

When I append data to another sheet with this code, some data is replaced when the range is uneven (i.e., one column has more data than another column). The last row is only based on one column, but I would need it to be based on 2 columns. How can I do this? Thank you!

```vb
Sub CopyData()

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastColumn As Long

  Set wsCopy = Sheets("CopyFrom")
  Set wsDest = Sheets("PasteHere")

  lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

  wsCopy.Range("C3:F20").Copy
  wsDest.Range("B" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial
  
  'Copy & Paste Date
  wsCopy.Range("B1").Copy
  wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another variable to store another column's length (I call it `tempLrow`), and then pick the highest value.
In the below answer I've used column A as the example but you could substitute in any other column - or do the same multiple times to get the maximum length across more different columns.

```
Sub CopyData()

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long, lDestLastRow As Long, lDestLastColumn As Long, tempLRow as Long

Set wsCopy = Sheets("CopyFrom"): Set wsDest = Sheets("PasteHere")

'Last row of column B:
lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
'Last row of column A:
tempLRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
' if column A is longer than column B, update lDestLastRow to suit:
If tempLRow > LDestLastRow Then LDestLastRow = tempLRow

wsCopy.Range("C3:F20").Copy Destination:=wsDest.Range("B" & lDestLastRow)
  
'Copy & Paste Date
wsCopy.Range("B1").Copy Destination:=wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)

End Sub
```